# Emscripten: How to bind an enum within a class as a property of the JS constructor?

Tags: emscripten

I bind a class with an public enum

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    enum class Bar { ALPHA, BRAVO }
};
Foo::Foo() { }

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Foo) {
    .enum_<Foo::Bar>("FooBar")
        .value("ALPHA", Foo::Bar::ALPHA)
        .value("BRAVO", Foo::Bar::BRAVO);
}
```

Now I can access the enum in Javascript via:

```
Module.FooBar.ALPHA
```

But actually I would like to access it via:

```
Module.Foo.Bar.ALPHA
```

Is there any chance to achieve this via Emscripten Bindings or is the following hackish JS code the only way?

```
Module.Foo.Bar = Module.FooBar;
delete Module.FooBar;
```

Answer (score 5):

I got an answer from [emscripten-discuss group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/BWEv60_yWi0)

> **jj**
>
> I don't think embind currently has such mechanism to namespace. The JS
>   code snippet you present looks like a good way (if it was tested to
>   work?). To encapsulate it nicely, you should be able to place it
>   inside an EM_ASM() block at the end of the bindings function in order
>   to make it self-contained and not have to maintain them in sync in
>   multiple places.

So, the result for the patch is:

```
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Foo) {
    .class_<Foo>("Foo");
    .enum_<Foo::Bar>("Foo.Bar")
        .value("ALPHA", Foo::Bar::ALPHA)
        .value("BRAVO", Foo::Bar::BRAVO);
    EM_ASM(
        Module['Foo']['Bar'] = Module['Foo.Bar'];
        delete Module['Foo.Bar'];
    );
}
```